# How to get pre-commit to ignore a necessary Behave function (error: E0102 PyLint)

Tags: python-3.x, bdd, python-behave

I'm using Behave as a python framework for testing. One of the necessary functions of Behave is `def step_imp(context):` but when I run pre-commit, I get loads of the following messages:

> E0102: function already defined line 26 (function-redefined)

I can't redefine this function, so is there a way to exclude this message specifically for the "step-imp" function?

Comment: this has nothing to do with pre-commit but whatever tool that's producing E0102

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the replies. There isn't more code relevant to my query. I just need to ignore this error message for all functions called step_imp as Behave requires all these functions to be named the same in order to work properly. Pre-commit is saying I should rename them but then Behave wouldn't work properly. So I need to ignore this specific error for functions called step_imp

Answer (score 0):

The information you provide is not enough to solve the problem.

Can you show the minimum example that reproduces this problem?

When using behave, although it is true that the name of all the functions is the same, they are differentiated by their tag, which avoids any error related to having several functions with the same name.

Example:
steps/steps.py

```
from behave import *


@given("This is one step")
def step_impl(context):
    print("I'm executing this code??")


@given("this is other setp")
def step_impl(context):
    print("or I'm executing this other code??")
```

As we can see, both methods have the same name but different tag, so for practical purposes they are different functions. If several of them share the same tag, we would have a duplicate.